# Как пофиксить такую ошибку?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Поставил билд. После чего билд закончился с ошибкой. Вот такая ошибка:

```
AAPT: error: 'url(#pattern0)' is incompatible with attribute fillColor (attr) color.
```

Код на который он ссылается:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="320dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="320"
    android:viewportHeight="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="url(#pattern0)"
        android:pathData="M0 15C0 6.71573 6.71573 0 15 0H305C313.284 0 320 6.71573 320 15V85C320 93.2843 313.284 100 305 100H15C6.71573 100 0 93.2843 0 85V15Z" />
</vector>
```

Как решить эту проблему?
Заранее спасибо, за ответ!

Comment: Что такое #pattern0?

Comment: @Bakhuss файл генерируется автоматически, без моего участия.

Comment: @nikita_game, поддержка векторной графики обрезанная. Скорее всего вам надо выкинуть `url(#pattern0)` и заменить его на что-то типа `00ff00`

Comment: android:fillColor="#ff00ff00"

Comment: @Style-7 Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб скорее всего вы правы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Я попробовал, но он автоматически заменил. https://prnt.sc/wjymgp

Comment: @nikita_game, непонятно как кто и почему что-то вам автоматически заменил. Опишите детально и пошагово как вы поменяли цвет и как и когда и кем он был изменён на старое значение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я удалил строчку url(#pattern0). И поставил android:fillColor="#ff00ff00". После чего начал билд и он просто автоматически заменил строчку. На url(#pattern0).

Comment: Крайне странно. А где находится этот ваш файл и как он в проекте появился?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб файл называется app\build\generated\res\pngs\debug\drawable-anydpi-v24\asd.xml:8: (Это путь)

Comment: Странно, что у вас файл в папке, которая каждый билд с нуля генерится. Если вы сами туда файл положили - то это неправильно в 99,(9)% случаев. Если не сами - то опишите максимально подробно как так вышло, что ваш файл - в этой папке.